# Multiple product views in WooCommerce with rollovers

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I am developing an ecommerce site with WooCommerce and I'm trying to add multiple product views that when clicked or on hover, replace the main image. The stock code opens the thumbnails attached to the post in fancy box, which I don't prefer. I have looked all over and found only a couple of plugins that come close but are still far away from my desired effect.

What I am looking for, ideally, is a plugin or code I can add to my functions that when you rollover a thumbnail it replaces the main image with the new one. If that isn't possible, I need it to at least replace it when clicked.

Any help is extraordinarily appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/ and it handles what I needed. I just set the zoom to inner so it doesn't open a zoom window and it has thumbnail hover that replaces the main image. Maybe this could help someone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't see why you need a plugin to do this at all, regular javascript/jQuery will work just fine.

```
 $( ".smallImage" ).hover(function() {
         var smallSrc = $(this).attr("src");
         $( "#bigImage" ).attr("src", src );
     }, function() {
         // Code here for mouse out
     }
 );
```